# component is added twice in dynamic placeholder

Tags: dynamic-placeholder

I'm using the [Integrated Dynamic Placeholders](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/I/Integrated_Dynamic_Placeholders.aspx) v1.2 and see the following 2 issues. Not sure if they are related.

1. In experience editor when I add `2 column 6-6` component, it shows the placeholder only for `col-wide-1`. It's not showing the placeholder for `col-wide-2`. [I gave them colored borders to identify.]

[image]

2. I have added the components via content editor. And when I check the page in Experience editor, it has added another `2 column 6-6` on its own.

[image]

[image]

**Section Centered.cshtml**

```
<section class="aboutUs">
    <div class="container">
        @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("section-centered")
    </div>
</section>
```

**2 column 6-6.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
        @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("col-wide-1")
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid green;">
        @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("col-wide-2")
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing any setting here. Using Sitecore 8.2 with MVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) For the col-wide-2, make sure the **Editable** checkbox is checked on the placeholder settings.

[image]

2) Have you perhaps added the 2-column-6-6 on the standard values of your template and then added it again through the page editor?

Comment: Thank you Koen. I did not add the placeholder `col-wide-2`. Any more thoughts on the 2nd issue. It is not a standard value, I checked.

Comment: Can you check the Shared and the Final layout?

Comment: Yes, the Final Layout had a different set of components. This never happened before. I removed all and added the reqd. set and it worked. Why did this happen. I always worked on only shared layout and the same would reflect for Final layout too.

Comment: @Qwerty When editing through Experience Editor, the default is the Final Layout. This means anything added through EE will go directly to Final Layout and skip Shared Layout, unless you specify you want to add to Shared Layout. Try looking at the Presentation Tab and changing the Layout selected.